# How to use Parse findObjectsInBackground to get objectID

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I am saving / retrieving images from Parse server successfully, but when I try and get the objectID my code crashes. How should I get the objectId to use for future reference e.g deleting the object?

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Images")

    query.findObjectsInBackground {
        (objects:[PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in

        if error == nil && (objects != nil) {
            for object in objects! {

                let imageFile = object["imageFileObject"] as! PFFileObject
                let imageWidth = object["imageWidth"] as! CGFloat
                let imageName = object["imageName"] as! String
                let imageId = object["objectId"] as! String  // CRASHES ON THIS LINE
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the `objectId` like this:

```swift
let imageId = object.objectId
```